# Does it affect the performance If I use CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync of Docoument DB c# SDK for every webapi request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb

We have multitenant app and for various reasons we need to have collection per tenant. We are planning to use the CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync for every request of one webapi service, that is expected to have large number of hits. Does it have any performance impact if I use this method with out implementing any sort of caching of collections created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you HAVE to call this API for every webapi request, then caching of collection(links) would obviously be better. But then you have to maintain this cache whenever new collections are added/deleted. I'm not sure how are you going to manage that efficiently.

In a good design, you don't create database/collection for every web request but have them pre-created as part of some initialization method and you just issue requests assuming that they exist. If any of the requests fail(say if the collection was deleted) that you can handle this exception appropriately and create a new collection in that case.

Also note these collection reads don't count towards the RUs that you provisioned on your collection since this is a "master" operation and not "server" operation. Master operations include Database CRUD and Collection CRUD and are allocated a fixed RU(in order of few hundred RUs) at your database account level. All your document requests count under server operations and they utilize the RU that you specify at your collection level.

So I'd not recommend you to use this API for EVERY webapi request.

If you have to use it selectively(during initialization or in any special cases), use the CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync API version in 1.11.1 that takes the DatabaseUri as the input for the best performance. The only "extra" call it does is ReadDocumentCollectionAsync before calling CreateDocumentCollectionAsync which is what the intent of this API is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was planning to cache the collection which has been created. I wanted to check if document db client does the caching of collection created internally..